# Karate Framework setup in VS code

Tags: karate

I am using the eclipse for my karate API project but i was thinking of using VS code and have few questions if someone can help please

1 Is karate free to use in VS code or do i need to purchase the license for karate pro ?

2 I manage to open my project and also download the Karate extension from marketplace but looks like it's not reading any variable from my karate config.js file

Apology if these questions have already been asked and answered.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is free to use and only advanced features require a subscription.

If you are using a Maven project, just [switch the extension configuration from `bundled` to `maven`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-vscode-extension/issues/14#issuecomment-1658142857) and `karate-config.js` should be picked up from the classpath.

Else, there is a configuration setting to add folders to the class-path, so refer this ticket to solve your issue with `karate-config.js`: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-vscode-extension/issues/14

Comment: Thank you for your reply Peter.  Really sorry, i did checked but couldn't find where exactly i need to change the extension configuration from bundled to maven in vs code?

Comment: @AjitThakkar see this link: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-vscode-extension/issues/14#issuecomment-1658142857