# org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "demoBaseUrl" is not defined for official demo project

Tags: karate

I cloned the Karate Repo https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/ and want to execute some Demo requests, like https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/greeting/greeting.feature, with VSCode (incl. Karate Plugin).

So I started the embedded Spring Boot App, and pressed the `run` CodeLens inline actions on the Feature level.

I got the following:

```
15:29:22.477 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - Karate version: 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT
15:29:22.656 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate.Suite - backed up existing 'target/karate-reports' dir to: target/karate-reports_1690982962654
15:29:23.111 [main]  ERROR com.intuit.karate - karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/greeting/greeting.feature:4
* url demoBaseUrl
js failed:
>>>>
01: demoBaseUrl
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "demoBaseUrl" is not defined
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)

karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/greeting/greeting.feature:4
```

[image]

java 17.0.7+7-LTS-sapmachine

I wonder what I am doing wrong that leads to that `demoBaseUrl` variable does not get initialized.

Comment: see this answer, can you please up-vote it and I will close this question as a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76787255/143475 - please note that the demo project is not a great "starter" project and you should look at the "karate-todo" instead: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-todo

Comment: thx for the tips. Opening the demo folder as root in VSCode did the job