# How to change/specify VS Code Karate Runner extension project directory?

Tags: vscode-extensions, karate

I have a workspace in VS Code with the following folders:

[VS Code Workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBLID.png)

When running the feature file, it was not able to detect my karate/karate-config.js file. On the karate tab, it is showing the "project" folder (see image below). And, all test reports are saved in "project" folder.

[Karate Runner Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCU9F.png)

I tried to re-arrange the folders in my workspace, moving the "karate" folder to the top, and everything works fine.

Comment: for the official karate vs code plugin, you can refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76787255/143475

Comment: hello, I tried changing the VS code settings (both user and workspace) as per [link](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-vscode-extension/issues/14#issuecomment-1524593692) but to no avail. I changed the value of `karatelabs-karate.run.classpathPrefix` to `./karate`, `.,karate`, `.,/karate`, etc. do you know what am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: sorry I can't help more than this. perhaps you are not using the plugin I am referring to (the official one) ? all the best

Comment: Apologies, I thought that `Karate` and `Karate Runner` are both official plugins. I have uninstalled `Karate Runner` but still experiencing the same issue. Anyway, I think I will just create another workspace with the 'karate' at the top. Thank you so much!

Comment: if you can help us replicate the problem (maybe a zip file) we will gladly look at the issue (you can raise it at the same link) but otherwise, hope you get this working